# BATS/Chi-X Europe Smart Order routing

Tags: stock-markets, europe

I have read that BATS/Chi-X Europe routes orders to other EU equity venues.  How can I determine what that list of venues is?

Comment: Have you tried contacting them and asking?

Comment: Not really, thought it would be publicly available?

Answer (score 1):

It is explained on [their website](http://www.batstrading.co.uk/features/).  Just look for the word "routing" on the Features page:

> Choose Your Venues
>
> Liquidity Pools
>
> Group 1: Bats Europe
>
> ```
> Start with the deep liquidity of Bats Europe’s dark and lit order books.
> ```
>
> Group 2: Liquidity Partner (LP)
>
> Add this group to access dark pool liquidity.
>
> ```
> Knight
> ```
>
> Group 3: Exchanges and MTFs
>
> Choose to access additional Exchanges and MTFs across Europe.
>
> ```
> London Stock Exchange, Borsa Italiana, Deutsche Börse, Euronext,
> SIX Swiss Exchange, Nasdaq OMX, Turquoise and Wiener Börse.
> ```